# Using Types from package dependancy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-router

The legacy project I am working on at work has types for the package 'history' twice in it. Once in `node_modules/@types/history/index.d.ts` (this uses version 4.7.2 of 'history'), and once in `node_modules/@types/react-router/node_modules/@types/history/index.d.ts` (using version 3.2 of 'history').

The type I am looking to use is stored in the second index.d.ts, or version 3.2, of 'history'. Is it possible to use that type? If I try:

```
import { Location } from 'history'
```

it imports from version 4.7.2 (`node_modules/@types/history/index.d.ts`) which doesn't match my code.

Comment: What version of `react-router` are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by importing like:

```
import { Location } from "react-router/node_modules/history";
```